# Run clojure file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, clojure

I have installed clojure plugins in eclipse so that I can start developing apps on clojure.  I am currently in the learning phase. I need to know how can i run a clojure file with a Keyboard shortcut or a single mouse button click in eclipse.

#### *Currently I am running this way,*

1. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, It launches the REPL
2. Then in the REPL I call the function name. For example (hello "world"). I have to type it in literaly in the REPL

#### *What I am looking for.*

1. I want to press a short cut key
2. The output after evaluating the current file should be displayed
   How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Clojure`-> `Load the file in REPL` or short cut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

It'll load the file in REPL and show the result.

Comment: First I thought It must be in the *Run* menu. As I always run projects via *Run* menu in eclipse. But I am mistaken. Its actually in *Clojure* menu.